# Using COM objects with WIA and com4j in Java

Tags: java, wia, com4j

I am a newbie in this and I wanted to ask if you could recommend me some articles, examples etc to start with communicating with scanner in java application
I am developing a module that should communicate with different scanners conected directly or in the local network... I would like WIA to start with and com4j..
thanks all for any advices :)

Edit: I came to some informations in this [Com4j tutorial](http://com4j.java.net/tutorial.html), that I need to generate some java type definitions from an ocx file.
If i had understand it, these generated classes will be my client to get the scanner using com4j. But what ocx/dll file shoud I use?
Anyone has idea?

**Update 1:** so I've managed to get the library to generate the wrapper classes, it was wiaaut.dll (Windows Image Acquisition Automation Library) and then via the ClassFactory I made an DeviceManager instance, but there are no devices in it...
How can I make the deviceManager to see the scanner on the local network?

**Update 2:** so i've discovered, that my HP LaserJet 2840 cant scan trough the network in win7 64 bit... now this question is answered, should I post the answer myself and set it to accepted, or close this Q other way? thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

so, my HP LaserJet 2840 cant scan trough the network in win7 64 bit

but the steps to use com objects like scanners or digital cameras in java are:

1. download and install the oleviewer from [MS Download center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5233b70d-d9b2-4cb5-aeb6-45664be858b6&displaylang=en) and in category Type Libraries, find the `Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition Library` or something similar and copy the location of the file (it should be `System32` directory)
2. then download them com4j jar file from [com4j website](http://com4j.java.net) and use the `tlbimp.jar` as shown [here](http://com4j.java.net/tutorial.html). It will generate the objects for you and now just use the `ClassFactory` to create the object to handle the com objects and go on with experimenting ;)

PS: maybe now it is easy but I had hard times to learn this :)